# Environment variables for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables

I am trying a number of different applications into my rails project. For security reasons, I am storing any sensitive keys as environment variables.
This is easy to do with Heroku but on the local environment side I find my windows environment variables starting to pile up. If I happen to have two projects with facebook authentication now I have to name them uniquely on my computer not to get mixed up with each others, which then means I have to rename them in my rails projects, which then means I need to rename them in Heroku... AH

Is there an easier way of doing this such as a configuration file that is added to gitignore, or is that still not quite safe?
What's the best practice for this?

Answer (score 3):

Rails 4.1 comes with `secrets.yml`, which is where you would put these. Please see [this section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml) of the Rails 4.1 release notes for more info.

Comment: So then would I add this to my gitignore. It seems like this is just adding secrets to my codebase...

Comment: This is the standard way of doing it within Rails 4.1. You should put these secrets securely onto your production server and copy them over into the `config/secrets.yml` location upon your application being deployed.

Comment: I guess I don't see the difference between config/secrets.yml and any ole file that I create to put secrets in. Why is this safe. The explanation on the site you sent doesn't cover this.

And do I have to upgrade to Rails 4.1 just to store secrets...

There has to be a standard way of doing this among the community.

Comment: The difference is that this is an officially supported feature of Rails.

Comment: Ryan, does `secrets.yml` work in production? How does it compare to setting ENV vars?

Comment: @RichPeck: Yes it does work in production. The difference is that `secrets.yml` keys are accessible through `Rails.application.config.secrets`, and ENV variables are accessible through the same old method.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Have you found them to be as secure?

Comment: @RichPeck If used in the recommended way, both are as secure as each other.